# two error messeges saying cant excute becuse missing files (wxmsw312u_core_vc_custom.dll,wxbase312u_vc_custom.dll) how to solve it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

i installed wxwidgets to visual studio 2019 first i install the wxwidgets for visual studio then i open "sln 15" then i buile it in debug,debug dll ,relese dll and relese then i i open project properties and change some properties to include include folder and liberary 
and then i copied the "hello world" example on widgets site but when i pressed the debug button to run the code two error messages showed up the first is cant execute because cant find"wxmsw312u_core_vc_custom.dll"
the second cant find"wxbase312u_vc_custom.dll"
the code is :
 `

```
// wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();
private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
};
enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Hello World")
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
    SetMenuBar( menuBar );
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
}
void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
                 "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}`
```

Comment: Please provide [edit] your question to include [mre], in the question itself, instead of being hidden behind external links.

Comment: @mohammadabdelhady, I presume you built the library yourself. In this case you should have the file `wxmsw312u_core_vc_custom.dll` inside the lib\vc_dll directory. Copy that file over to the folder where you `hello_world.exe` is located and try again. But it is much better to open the wxWidgets\samples\minimal\minimal_vc15.sln and build/run it.

Comment: i copied these files to the project file and it worked

Comment: do i have to build the library my self every time i want to create a project with wxwidgets or can i just copy this project and write over the code

Answer (score 0):

When you build wxWidgets libraries as DLLs, you need these DLLs to run the applications using them, just as with any other DLL. The DLLs don't need to be in the same directory as the application (although it does work if you do it like this), you may also add the directory containing them to your `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, build wxWidgets as static libraries -- then you won't have any run-time dependencies on them.